# Интерпретатор Python обращается не к тому модулю

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, pyautogui

В процессе ознакомления с модулем **pyautogui**, при попытке просто найти позицию курсора интерпретатор почему-то обращается к **tkinter**, который даже не упоминается в коде.

**Код:**

```
import pyautogui as pag

print(pag.position())
```

**Ответ интерпретатора:**

```
NOTE: You must install tkinter on Linux to use MouseInfo. Run the following: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev
```

Comment: очень редко модули в питоне (и в других языках, как бы они там не назывались) самодостаточные. Очень часто  они под капотом используют другие (особенно тут отметилась node.js+npm:) ). Поэтому да, установите себе нужный модуль и работайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо скачать модуль. Это делается Вот так.
1.1: написать в командую строку `pip install pyautogui`
1.1.1: Если вышла ошибка что pip не установлен надо переустановить python и поставить галочку на `pip` и на самом начале на `add to the PATH`
1.1.2: Если выйдет куча проблем то лучше посмотреть на видео https://youtu.be/CgCJwDjm_Cw?t=63