# Проблема с установкой модуля pip. Что делать?

Tags: python, pip

```sh
D:\depython>pip pyowm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Это выбивает не только с `pyowm`. Как мне решить проблему?

Comment: Наверное, надо переустановить pip...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1318053/421863
Я отвечал на вопрос раньше. Вот ссылка на ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете консоль Windows, то нужно писать

```
pip install "название библиотеки"
```

например:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Если вылетает с ошибкой `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`, то добавление install проблему решить не может.